# Azure Devops terraform modules sourcing

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I've been researching and going back and forth on a lot of topics, yet I may have not understood clearly so I'm looking for guidance.
I have an azure devops account where I currently have two projects.
Project A
Project B

In project A I created 3 repositories - each repository is a terraform module.
Project A - repostitories: 1) virtual network module 2) resource group module 3) virtual machine module

Project B is where I have my pipeline and my main.tf where I would like to call the module using the source.

I would not like to use scripts to pre-download modules, I'd like to use the format alongside with release tags for different releases of the same module.

```
  source = "git::https://dev.azure.com/loredan6/Terraform%20Code/_git/ResourceGroup"
  # Resource Group Variables

  az_rg_name     = "ResourceGroup-Name"
  az_rg_location = "UK South"

  az_tags = {
    Environment   = "Development"
    CostCenter    = "Department"
    ResourceOwner = "Example Owner"
    Project       = "Project Name"
    Role          = "Resource Group"
  }
}
```

```
Initializing modules...
Downloading git::https://dev.azure.com/loredan6/Terraform%20Code/_git/ResourceGroup for az-resource-group...
╷
│ Error: Failed to download module
│ 
│ Could not download module "az-resource-group" (main.tf:20) source code from
│ "git::https://dev.azure.com/loredan6/Terraform%20Code/_git/ResourceGroup":
│ error downloading
│ 'https://dev.azure.com/loredan6/Terraform%20Code/_git/ResourceGroup':
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 128: Cloning into
│ '.terraform/modules/az-resource-group'...
│ fatal: could not read Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': terminal
│ prompts disabled
```

The error is the one above. Any suggestions or a good guide on how to achieve this? is this even possible?

Comment: Are you logged into devops so that you can use git clone on the same repo? The error looks authentication related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue was related to the association of the System.AccessToken which wasn't passed on properly. after figuring that out , everything works perfectly fine. indeed authentication was the primary issue.

Comment: Hi, Calimanu, thanks for your post and kindly sharing. To benefit more developers and users, you could highlight this solution to help them with the similar scenario